# object constructor list in Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I recently started learning Node.js and I want to know how to let a function accept multiple strings in the form of an array. For example,

```
export default (config: Config) => {
  return {
    target: 'https://google.com',
    endpoint: null,
    tick: 500,
    verbose: true,
    once: false,
    }
}
```

So instead of `target: "https://google.com"`, I'd like something like `target: ['https://google.com', 'https://facebook.com']`. There's probably something I'm missing but I'm a bit lost on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). The syntax is

```
 const hello = (...args) => {
     // args is now an array
     console.log(args)
 }
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
hello('This ', 'is ', 'an ', 'example') // outputs ['This ', 'is ', 'an ', 'example']
```

You can pass any number of arguments in it.

So back to your example, you could have some like

```
const example = (...targets) => {
  return {
    target: targets,
    endpoint: null,
    tick: 500,
    verbose: true,
    once: false,
  }
}

module.exports = example
```

And you can use it like so

```
const example = require('./example')

let val = example('google', 'twitter', 'yahoo')
console.log(val)
```

Rest parameter should be the last parameter in your function. So if you want to pass some other params, the syntax is

```
function hello(param, ...rest) {
    // rest is an array
    ...
}
```

You could also directly pass an array or a variable referencing an array:

```
function hello(param) {
    ...
    console.log(param)
}

hello(["hello", "world"]) // outputs ["hello", "world"]
or
var arr = ["hello", "world"]
hello(arr)
```

You can also read more about the [Array-like object arguments here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)